# Selenium on python chrome driver keeps on crashing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the code in vs code, the website I'm trying to run on selenium keeps on opening for a second then crash after. It doesn't show any error in when I run it.

I tried different tutorials of how to run it, but nothing worked.

Comment: Pleas read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit you question